# Фон для смартфона

Tags: css, background

Необходимо, чтобы фон для компьютера состоял из картинки, а для мобильных устройств из цвета. Как это примерно сделать я знаю, но не получается — на мобильных устройствах все равно отображается фон из картинки.

```css
body {
  background-color: #EDEEF0;
  background: url(/img/bg.png) repeat;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
  body {
    background-color: #EDEEF0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Универсальное свойство `background` позволяет установить одновременно до пяти характеристик фона. Значения могут идти в любом порядке, браузер сам определит, какое из них соответствует нужному свойству. Для подробного ознакомления смотрите информацию о каждом свойстве отдельно ([ссылка](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background)) .

Что касается `background-image`- устанавливает фоновое изображение для элемента. Если одновременно для элемента задан цвет фона, он будет показан, пока фоновая картинка не загрузится полностью. То же произойдет, если изображения не доступны или их показ в браузере отключен. В случае наличия в рисунке прозрачных областей, через них будет проглядывать фоновый цвет.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(/img/bg.png) repeat;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
  body {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #EDEEF0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
     background: url(/img/bg.png) repeat;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
    body {
        background: #EDEEF0;
    }
}
```